# API JSON get ID from bash

Tags: json, bash, curl

Just wondering if someone could help me get the "SNAPSHOTID" from the first record that is output from a CURL command which outputs the below? I have tried JQ but i get

> "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6"

Any other ideas?

```
{  
   "9875a8e4fc31f3":{  
      "SNAPSHOTID":"98758e4afc31f3",
      "date_created":"2017-04-05 10:16:17",
      "description":"centminmod",
      "size":"42949672960",
      "status":"complete"
   },
   "b0d58e5b0d46e":{  
      "SNAPSHOTID":"b0d58e5b0d46e",
      "date_created":"2017-04-05 23:07:00",
      "description":"serverpilot",
      "size":"42949672960",
      "status":"complete"
   },
   "d3158e6fbaa204":{  
      "SNAPSHOTID":"d3a158e6fba204",
      "date_created":"2017-04-06 22:38:26",
      "description":"",
      "size":"42949672960",
      "status":"complete"
   },
   "39a58ae6fe12f0":{  
      "SNAPSHOTID":"39aa58e6fe1a2f0",
      "date_created":"2017-04-06 22:48:50",
      "description":"",
      "size":"42949672960",
      "status":"complete"
   },
   "51458ea70124c7":{  
      "SNAPSHOTID":"514a58e701a24c7",
      "date_created":"2017-04-06 23:01:56",
      "description":"",
      "size":"42949672960",
      "status":"complete"
   },
   "b2a58e7a04af99":{  
      "SNAPSHOTID":"b2a5a8e70a4af99",
      "date_created":"2017-04-06 23:17:03",
      "description":"",
      "size":"42949672960",
      "status":"complete"
   },
   "17b58e70a7133c":{  
      "SNAPSHOTID":"17b58ae7a07133c",
      "date_created":"2017-04-06 23:27:15",
      "description":"",
      "size":"42949672960",
      "status":"complete"
   },
   "32958e70aa0acf":{  
      "SNAPSHOTID":"32958eaa70a0acf",
      "date_created":"2017-04-06 23:39:54",
      "description":"",
      "size":"42949672960",
      "status":"complete"
   },
   "dfa58e70d63a57":{  
      "SNAPSHOTID":"dfa58ea70d6357",
      "date_created":"2017-04-06 23:54:11",
      "description":"",
      "size":"42949672960",
      "status":"complete"
   },
   "96358e712bf80":{  
      "SNAPSHOTID":"96358e7a12bf80",
      "date_created":"2017-04-07 00:17:03",
      "description":"",
      "size":"0",
      "status":"pending"
   }
}
```

Comment: go with `jq` ,if you dont have it try `grep -oP 'SNAPSHOTID":"\K[^"]+' input.json`

Comment: Do provide feedback on the provided answer  and mark it resolved it it solved your problem

Comment: Can you let know if the solution worked?

Comment: Please show us the script that gave the listed error

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap the 'SNAPSHOTID' into an array then you can extract it like this

```
curl --silent http://url.to.json | jq '[.[].SNAPSHOTID] | .[0]'
```

The --silent switch taken from `man curl`

> **-s, --silent**
>       Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages. 
>       Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit overcomplicated but works:

`grep SNAPSHOTID | head -n 1 | sed "s/[^\"']*.SNAPSHOTID.[^\"']*.\([^\"']*\).*/\1/"`

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `to_entries`, then you generate an array and can directly index which section you want, e.g.:

```
<test.json jq 'to_entries | first | .value.SNAPSHOTID'
```

Output:

```
"98758e4afc31f3"
```